# Subquery - define select list. The subquery returns the same value for each result line

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, selectlist

do you know what I have done wrong?
My subquery is returining the same value for all lines.

```
SELECT distinct
ca.descripcion AS 'Storage_Condition',
--Warehouses.[Nombre] as [Warehouse],
COUNT(pos.rack) as [Max Capacity],

(select distinct 
count(pos.rack) + ''
FROM Depositos de
INNER JOIN Posiciones pos ON  de.deposito_id = pos.deposito_id
INNER JOIN Condiciones_Almacenamiento ca ON  de.condicion_almac_id = ca.condicion_id
INNER JOIN Estados_Posicion ep ON  pos.estado_posicion_id = ep.estado_posicion_id 
INNER JOIN Tipo_posiciones tipopos ON tipopos.tipo_posicion_id = pos.tipo_posicion_id 
INNER JOIN Warehouses ON   Warehouses.[warehouse_id] = de.[warehouse_id]
WHERE ((CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN ep.descripcion_es ELSE ep.descripcion END) = 'Occupied') AND tipopos.descripcion = 'Shelf' AND Warehouses.nombre like ('%Frankfurt%')) as [Used Capacity]

FROM  Depositos de

INNER JOIN Posiciones pos ON  de.deposito_id = pos.deposito_id
-- AND  de.warehouse_id = @warehouse_id
INNER JOIN Condiciones_Almacenamiento ca ON  de.condicion_almac_id = ca.condicion_id
INNER JOIN Tipos_Subproyecto ts ON  de.tipo_subproyecto_id = ts.tipo_subproyecto_id
INNER JOIN Estados_Posicion ep ON  pos.estado_posicion_id = ep.estado_posicion_id
INNER JOIN Tipo_posiciones tipopos ON tipopos.tipo_posicion_id = pos.tipo_posicion_id 
INNER JOIN Warehouses ON   Warehouses.[warehouse_id] = de.[warehouse_id]
where 
--ca.descripcion = '15-25.C'
tipopos.descripcion = 'Shelf'
and Warehouses.nombre like ('%Frankfurt%')
--and (CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN ep.descripcion_es ELSE ep.descripcion END) = 'Occupied'

Group by 
--Warehouses.[Nombre] 
ca.descripcion
Order by COUNT(pos.rack) desc
```

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance for your any advice! :)

Comment: Your subquery is not correlated, it is separate - of course it returns the same value (moreover, it is executed once). If you wait this subquery to be correlated then remove aliases ambiguity at least. PS. Thу suquery row source is too similar to one of outer query source - so do you need in subquery at all? maybe conditional aggregation wil be enough?

Comment: Incidentally, it is unlikely (but not impossible) that you will ever need a construction like `DISTINCT [aggregate_function]`. You can assume it's wrong.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ca.descripcion AS Storage_Condition,
       count(pos.rack) as [Max Capacity],
       sum(case when ep.descripcion = 'Occupied' then 1 else 0 end) as used_capacity
FROM  Depositos de JOIN
      Posiciones pos
      ON  de.deposito_id = pos.deposito_id JOIN
      Condiciones_Almacenamiento ca
      ON de.condicion_almac_id = ca.condicion_id JOIN
      Tipos_Subproyecto ts
      ON  de.tipo_subproyecto_id = ts.tipo_subproyecto_id JOIN
      Estados_Posicion ep
      ON  pos.estado_posicion_id = ep.estado_posicion_id JOIN
      Tipo_posiciones tipopos
      ON tipopos.tipo_posicion_id = pos.tipo_posicion_id JOIN
      Warehouses
      ON  Warehouses.[warehouse_id] = de.[warehouse_id]
WHERE tipopos.descripcion = 'Shelf' and
      Warehouses.nombre like '%Frankfurt%'
GROUP BY ca.descripcion
ORDER BY COUNT(pos.rack) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly I needed!